# Why is this crashing? - C

Tags: c

I am so close to finishing this, at least i hope so because if I'm not I'm going to go insane. I've managed to get rid of all of the syntax and errors to get rid of compiler, I start it in hopes that I would finally be done and then... it crashes...

To give a bit of an overview of how it's suppose to work, it's suppose to print out five values from the 'deck' - then randomly shuffle it the print again (to show it shuffled)

I'm so close. I can taste it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 52

enum faces{Ace = 0, Jack = 10, Queen, King};
char * facecheck(int d); 
void shuffle( int deck[]);
void draw(int deck[SIZE]); 
void cards(int hand);
int main() 
{ 
    int deck[SIZE], i, n;
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};


    srand( time( NULL ) ) ;

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = i;
        i++;
    };

    draw(deck);
    shuffle(deck); 
    draw(deck);




    return 0; 
}  

char * facecheck(int d)
{
    static char * face[] = 
    {
        "Ace",
        "Jack",
        "Queen",
        "King" };

    if(d == Ace)
        return face[0];
    else
    {
        if(d == Jack) 
            return face[1];
        else
        {
            if(d == Queen)
                return face[2];
            else 
            { 
                if(d == King)
                    return face[3];
            }
        }
    }
}



void shuffle( int deck[]) 
{
     int i, j, temp; 

     for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     {
           j = rand() % SIZE; 
           temp = deck[i];
           deck[i] = deck[j];
           deck[j] = temp;
           }
     printf("The deck has been shuffled \n"); 
} 

void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
     int i; 
     int hand[i];

     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
           cards(hand[i]);
           putchar('\n');
           }
}

void cards(hand)
{
     int i; 

         char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};

         for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {       
        if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
            printf("%s ", facecheck(i%13) );
        else printf("%d ", i%13+1);
        printf("of %s \n", suits[i/13]);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please post the error message ?

Comment: I hate to say this because you're obviously doing efforts already, but normally we would ask you to provide a very small snippet of code that you know is causing the problem. What's your operating system? Because we could at least suggest debuggers that are going to let you see exactly where it crashes.

Comment: @ Anakata, there is no error message, it compilers just fine. but when i try to load it in the compiler it just fails

@zneak I use 64-bit windows 7, I also don't know what the problem is, else I'd do exactly that.

Comment: A debugger is your best friend for crashes. Even outputs can help to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: "I start it in hopes that I would finally be done" -- Sorry, that's not how it works, especially for beginner unexperienced programmers who are bound to have multiple logic errors in their code.

Comment: "I also don't know what the problem is, else I'd do exactly that. " -- You've got the cart before the horse. Using your debugger (Visual Studio?) will help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: "I'm so close. I can taste it! " -- Except for the numerous blatant bugs, sure. For instance, why does `draw` take a `deck` argument it never uses? Why does `cards` take a `hands` argument that it never uses? Programming requires care and precision.

Answer (score 2):

It probably crashes because here:

```
for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    deck[i] = i;
    i++;
};
```

you increment i twice.
Remove the `i++` line:

```
for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    deck[i] = i;
};
```

Also, here:

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
     int i; 
     int hand[i];
```

the line `int hand[i]` will probably fail because i is not a constant (it's not initialized also).

Comment: w/r/t `int hand[i]`, at that point `i=0` and `int hand[0]` is acceptable on some compilers (eg [**GNU C**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)).  So, it might not fail or crash, maybe throw warning depending on your compile flags.  It is almost definitely unintended though.

Comment: @jedwards, gcc will allow variable-length arrays, so it's kind of moot.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
    int i; 
    int hand[i];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cards(hand[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

`i` is not initialized by default, and will contain whatever was in that memory address before, then you create an array of this random length -- do you mean to do this?

Then you pass hand[0], hand[1], ..., hand[4] to cards even though they're undefined.

This could cause a crash.

Maybe you want something like:

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE])
{
    int numCards = 5;
    int i; 
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
    {
        card = deck[i];     /* Draw a card */
        hand[i] = card;     /* Store it in a "hand" array (even though you dont use it) */
        cards(card);        /* Display info about the card */
    }
}
```

---

Here you print out what the integer value of every card would be, regardless of how your deck is sorted.

```
void cards(hand)
{
    int i; 

    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {       
        if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
            printf("%s ", facecheck(i%13) );
        else 
            printf("%d ", i%13+1);
        printf("of %s \n", suits[i/13]);
    }

}
```

I don't think you mean to do this.  I think you mean something like

```
void cards(int card)
{
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};


    if(card%13 == 0 || card%13 == 10 || card%13 == 11 || card%13 == 12)
        printf("%s ", facecheck(card%13) );
    else 
        printf("%d ", card%13+1);
    printf("of %s \n", suits[card/13]);
}
```

Since you're already calling this function on each card, no reason to loop through anything.

Comment: "i is initialized by default to 0" -- No it isn't.

Comment: I was thinking C#, but I figured it was one of the two. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    deck[i] = i;
    i++;
};
```

the error of semicolon in for-loop?

```
for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    deck[i] = i;
    i++; //one of the answer stated to remove this sentence
}
```